# Perl: Replacing links (html) that meet certain criteria

Tags: regex, perl

On my forum, I want to automatically add **rel="nofollow"** to links that point to external sites. For instance, someone creates a post with the following text:

```
Link 1: <a href="http://www.external1.com" target="_blank">External Link 1</A>
Link 2: <a href="http://www.myforum.com">Local Link 1</A>
Link 3: <a href="http://www.external2.com">External Link 2</A>
Link 4: <a href="http://www.myforum.com/test" ALT="Local">Local Link 2</A>
```

Using Perl, I want that changed to:

```
Link 1: <a href="http://www.external1.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">External Link 1</A>
Link 2: <a href="http://www.myforum.com">Local Link 1</A>
Link 3: <a href="http://www.external2.com" rel="nofollow">External Link 2</A>
Link 4: <a href="http://www.myforum.com/test" ALT="Local">Local Link 2</A>
```

I can do this using quite a few lines of code, but I was hoping I could do this with one or more regexes. But I can't figure out how.

Comment: Do you allow arbitrary HTML in the posts? Or do you use some other markup language like BB code – in that case, augmenting the parser for that might be better.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Perl, really, but would something like: "(.*?href=/"http:////www/.myforum/.com/".*?)(.*?>.*)" be your regex, and then if that matchs, it's local, otherwise it's not. And then if it's not you find "(.*?href=.*?)(>.*)" and replace what you found with the first element + " rel=/"nofollow/"" + the second element?

Comment: @amon: Yes, the forum uses a markup language but posts are stored in their HTML form.

Comment: @AlexBaldwin: That would only work if there's only one link in the string.

Comment: @ClarkVentura , You're right. I was trying to make it work with the example given, and didn't pay attention to the real world problem he mentioned. However, if coupled with a regex that simply finds all links, you could then use my old regex on each link found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a regex gobal and eval flag for callback, eg like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $internal_link = qr'href="https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?myforum\.com';

my $html = '
Lorem ipsum
<a href="http://www.external1.com" target="_blank">External Link 1</A>
Lorem ipsum
<a href="http://www.myforum.com">Local Link 1</A>
Lorem ipsum
<a href="http://www.external2.com">External Link 2</A>
Lorem ipsum
<a href="http://www.myforum.com/test" ALT="Local">Local Link 2</A>
';

$html =~ s/<a ([^>]+)>/"<a ". replace_externals($1). ">"/eg;

print $html;

sub replace_externals {
    my ($inner) = @_;
    return $inner =~ $internal_link ? $inner : "$inner rel=\"nofollow\"";
}
```

Alternatively you can surely use [negative look-aheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but that would just mess up the readability..

Comment: Ooooooo! I had never worked with evals in regex's before but that looks like it should work beautifully! Thanks!

Comment: BTW I had already tried to do it with negative look-aheads, but that didn't work (since it would simply skip over the non-local links until it found a local link and mash the two links together - hard to explain but if you try it, you'll see what I mean).

Answer (score 1):

Regexes can work in limited scenarios, but you should never use regexes to parse HTML

> Every time you attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, the unholy child weeps the blood of virgins, and Russian hackers pwn your webapp.
>
> — from [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1521179)

I am quite fond of the Mojo suite, because this allows us to use a proper parser with very little code. We can the use CSS selectors to find interesting elements:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use autodie;
use Mojo;
use File::Slurp;

for my $filename (@ARGV) {
  my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(scalar read_file $filename);

  for my $link ($dom->find('a[href]')->each) {
    $link->attr(rel => 'nofollow')
      if $link->attr('href') !~ m(\Ahttps?://www[.]myforum[.]com(?:/|\z));
  }

  write_file "$filename~", "$dom";
  rename "$filename~" => $filename;
}
```

Invocation: `perl mark-links-as-nofollow.pl *.html` A test run on your data produces the output:

```
Link 1: <a href="http://www.external1.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">External Link 1</a>
Link 2: <a href="http://www.myforum.com">Local Link 1</a>
Link 3: <a href="http://www.external2.com" rel="nofollow">External Link 2</a>
Link 4: <a alt="Local" href="http://www.myforum.com/test">Local Link 2</a>
```

Why did I use tempfiles and `rename`? On most file systems, a file can be renamed atomically, whereas writing to a file takes some time. So other processes might see a half-written file.

- [Mojolicious Website](http://mojolicio.us/)
- [`Mojo::DOM` documentation](http://p3rl.org/Mojo::DOM)